# nested types on EDB

Tags: postgresql, edb

I'm having problems on a migration of plsql application to edb.
The current problem is, than we have nested types, like:

```
 TYPE personas_rt IS RECORD (adulto numeric, nino numeric);  
 TYPE personas_aat IS TABLE OF personas_rt   INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
 TYPE room_type_rt IS RECORD (id numeric, personas_aa personas_aat);
 TYPE room_type_aat  IS TABLE OF room_type_rt         INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

and in oracle plsql procedure, i can do something like:

```
 hab_list (1).personas_aa (1).adulto := 2;
```

my question iis, how can do this in edb?

I tried to put parentheses and brackets everywhere, but I can't find the solution.

It is surely a very silly question, but could you tell me the syntax to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could create types like this in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TYPE personas_rt AS (adulto bigint, nino bigint);
CREATE TYPE room_type_rt AS (id bigint, personas_aa personas_rt[]);
```

Then if you have a record `hab_list` of type `room_type_rt[]`, you could do this in PL/pgSQL:

```
((hab_list[1]).personal_aa[1]).adulto := 2;
```

But often it is a good idea to unravel this unspeakable mess of nesting, which does not go well with relational database design.